# r mongolite - date query

Tags: r, mongolite

**Question**

Using the `mongolite` package in `R`, how do you query a database for a given date?

**Example Data**

Consider a `test` collection with two entries

```
library(mongolite)

## create dummy data
df <- data.frame(id = c(1,2),
                 dte = as.POSIXct(c("2015-01-01","2015-01-02")))

> df
  id        dte
1  1 2015-01-01
2  2 2015-01-02

## insert into database
mong <- mongo(collection = "test", db = "test", url = "mongodb://localhost")
mong$insert(df)
```

**Mongo shell query**

To find the entries after a given date I would use

```
db.test.find({"dte" : {"$gt" : new ISODate("2015-01-01")}})
```

How can I reproduce this query in `R` using `mongolite`?

**R attempts**

So far I have tried

```
qry <- paste0('{"dte" : {"$gt" : new ISODate("2015-01-01")}}')
mong$find(qry)
Error: Invalid JSON object: {"dte" : {"$gt" : new ISODate("2015-01-01")}}

qry <- paste0('{"dte" : {"$gt" : "2015-01-01"}}')
mong$find(qry)
 Imported 0 records. Simplifying into dataframe...
    data frame with 0 columns and 0 rows

qry <- paste0('{"dte" : {"gt" : ', as.POSIXct("2015-01-01"), '}}')
mong$find(qry)
Error: Invalid JSON object: {"dte" : {"gt" : 2015-01-01}}

qry <- paste0('{"dte" : {"gt" : new ISODate("', as.POSIXct("2015-01-01"), '")}}')
mong$find(qry)
Error: Invalid JSON object: {"dte" : {"gt" : new ISODate("2015-01-01")}}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

@user2754799 has the correct method, but I've made a couple of small changes so that it answers my question. If they want to edit their answer with this solution I'll accept it.

```
d <- as.integer(as.POSIXct(strptime("2015-01-01","%Y-%m-%d"))) * 1000
## or more concisely
## d <- as.integer(as.POSIXct("2015-01-01")) * 1000
data <- mong$find(paste0('{"dte":{"$gt": { "$date" : { "$numberLong" : "', d, '" } } } }'))
```

Comment: Because 
    as.integer(as.POSIXct("2017-06-08", tz="GMT", origin = "1970-01-01"))*1000
returns  1.49688e+12, I suggest pasting "000" instead of multiplying by 1000.

Answer (score 7):

as this question keeps showing up at the top of my google results when i forget AGAIN how to query dates in `mongolite` and am too lazy to go find the documentation:

the above Mongodb shell query,

`db.test.find({"dte" : {"$gt" : new ISODate("2015-01-01")}})`

now translates to

`mong$find('{"dte":{"$gt":{"$date":"2015-01-01T00:00:00Z"}}}')`

optionally, you can add millis:

`mong$find('{"dte":{"$gt":{"$date":"2015-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"}}}')`

if you use the wrong datetime format, you get a helpful error message pointing you to the correct format: `use ISO8601 format yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm plus timezone, either "Z" or like "+0500"`

of course, this is also documented in [the mongolite manual](https://jeroen.github.io/mongolite/query-data.html#select-by-date)

Comment: ... and here I am finding your answer AGAIN on the same question ;)

Answer (score 4):

try mattjmorris's answer from github

```
library(GetoptLong)
datemillis <- as.integer(as.POSIXct("2015-01-01")) * 1000
data <- data_collection$find(qq('{"createdAt":{"$gt": { "$date" : { "$numberLong" : "@{datemillis}" } } } }'))
```

reference: https://github.com/jeroenooms/mongolite/issues/5#issuecomment-160996514

Comment: what's the function `qq` ?

Comment: it's a function from package `GetoptLong`

Answer (score 1):

Prior converting your date by multiplying it with 1000, do this: `options(scipen=1000)`, as the lack of this workaround will affect certain dates.

This is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36562894/r-converting-posixct-to-milliseconds?noredirect=1&lq=1#_=_):