# r - converting POSIXct to milliseconds

Tags: r, posixct

From `?POSIXct` we know that

> Class "POSIXct" represents the (signed) number of seconds since the beginning of 1970 (in the UTC time zone) as a numeric vector.

Therefore, I've assumed that to get a `POSIXct` value in milliseconds we need to multiply by `1000`

---

Consider the days in December 2015

```
## generate sequence of days in December 2015
d <- seq(as.POSIXct("2015-12-01"), as.POSIXct("2015-12-31"), by = 60*60*24)
#  [1] "2015-12-01 AEDT" "2015-12-02 AEDT" 
#  ...
# [29] "2015-12-29 AEDT" "2015-12-30 AEDT" "2015-12-31 AEDT"
```

Converting them to integer

```
d <- as.integer(d)
```

We see that each integer is `10` digits

```
nchar(d)
# [1] 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10
```

When multiplying by 1000 to convert to milliseconds we get

```
nchar(d * 1000)
# [1] 13 13 13 13 12 13 13 13 13 12 13 13 13 13 12 13 13 13 13 11 13 13 13 13 12 13 13 13 13 12 13
```

some values are only 11 or 12 digits (whereas I would have thought multiplying a 10-digit number by 1000 would add 3 digits)

Is there an explanation for this that I'm not seeing?

Comment: Take a look at `lapply(c(11,12,13), function(x) d[nchar(d*1000) %in% x] )` and look at the last 4 digits, 3 digits and 2 digits of the returned values.

Comment: And also consider `lapply(c(10e5, 10e6, 10e7), nchar)`

Comment: @thelatemail - thanks, I **see** what you're getting at. However, I still don't fully understand what's (or probably more accurately why) going on :)

Comment: trailing zeros? too big to store as integer so its a sci notation and trailing zeros eaten by pacman

Comment: It's to do with how numbers are printed in scientific format - e.g.: `options(scipen=1000); nchar(d*1000)` gives the result you expect. It probably doesn't make sense to use a character function to assess numeric data really.

Comment: @thelatemail - so it would appear - `floor( log10 (d * 1000)) + 1` for example,

Comment: @Symbolix - looks like you can answer your own question and reap those sweet reputation points  ;-)

Comment: @thelatemail - :-) I've added some background to show **why** I asked the question in the first place too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Summary answer

The short answer to this is to do with how numbers are printed in scientific format

To see this we can set `options(scipen=1000)` and we get the result as expected.

```
options(scipen=1000); 
nchar(d*1000)
# [1] 13 13 13 13 13 13 13 13 13 13 13 13 13 13 13 13 13 13 13 13 13 13 13 13 13 13 13 13 13 13 13
```

---

### longer answer

The background to this question came from trying to query a **mongodb** database using a date range in `library(mongolite)`

For example, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34454034/5977215) and [this issue](https://github.com/jeroenooms/mongolite/issues/5#issuecomment-160996514) show that to query a date it needs to be converted to `numberLong` for the query to work correctly.

To illistrate this, and the issue I was having, consider this data and subsequent queries

```
library(mongolite)

df <- data.frame(date = as.POSIXct(c("2015-12-19","2015-12-20","2015-12-21")),
                 val = c(1,2,3))

mongo <- mongo(collection = "test", db = "test", url = "mongodb://localhost")

## insert data into test database
mongo$insert(df)

## querying the 19th December 2015 works as expected, because d is formatted with 13 digits
d <- as.integer(as.POSIXct("2015-12-19")) * 1000
q <- paste0('{"date" : {"$date" : { "$numberLong" : "', d,'" } } }')
mongo$find(query = q)
# 
# Imported 1 records. Simplifying into dataframe...
# date val
# 1 2015-12-19   1

## the 20th December 2015 errors, as d is formatted with < 13 digits
d <- as.integer(as.POSIXct(("2015-12-20"))) * 1000
q <- paste0('{"date" : {"$date" : { "$numberLong" : "', d,'" } } }')
mongo$find(query = q)
#
# Error: Invalid input string 1.45053e+12, looking for 11

## the 21st December 2015 works as expected because d is formatted with 13 digits.
d <- as.integer(as.POSIXct("2015-12-21")) * 1000
q <- paste0('{"date" : {"$date" : { "$numberLong" : "', d,'" } } }')
mongo$find(query = q)
#
# Imported 1 records. Simplifying into dataframe...
# date val
# 1 2015-12-21   3

## cleanup 
rm(mongo); gc()
```

So to resolve this I either need to set `options(scipen=1000)`, or right-pad my `d` with zeroes when it goes into the query.

Comment: If you're writing a package note that you can't just put `options(...)` at the top of the package, you have to put it in a function.