# R : Querying MongoDB by timestamp (using mongolite)

Tags: r, mongodb, mongolite

I have a sizeable Mongo database that is indexed based on `timestamp`. Each timestamp in the database is structured in the following way:

```
"timestamp" : ISODate("2016-05-22T17:05:22.000Z")
```

I am an R user and I am attempting to query the database with respect to the timestamp of each entry. Specifically, I would like to retrieve all entries that have a timestamp greater than some date that I specify. I am currently using the `mongolite` package to query MongoDB through R but am getting no success.

Here is an example of the query I am using to retrieve the data suing `mongolite` :

```
library(mongolite)

mongo <- mongolite::mongo(url = "mongodb://localhost:27017", 
                      collection = "testCol", 
                      db = "testDB")

fmt <- '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.000Z'

rawData <- mongo$find(query = paste0('{
                                       "timestamp" : { 
                                                      "$gte" : "ISODate(', format(Sys.time() - (60 * 60 * 24), fmt),')", 
                                                      "$lt" : "ISODate(', format(Sys.time(), fmt),')" 
                                                     } 
                                      }'))
```

Note that I am formatting the time and date to align with the MongoDB format above and that I am attempting to extract all entries over the past 24 hours. I also add some fields in my actual query, but have not included them here.

Is there something obviously wrong with this query?

Comment: Did you mean `fmt <- '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.000%Z' `or do all your timestamps end in the letter "Z"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to convert the date into a `numberLong`, and query on that

```
d <- as.integer(Sys.time()) * 1000

rawData <- mong$find(paste0('{"timestamp":{"$gte": { "$date" : { "$numberLong" : "', d, '" } } } }'))
```

I have a [very similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36562894/5977215)

And see [this thread](https://github.com/jeroenooms/mongolite/issues/5#issuecomment-160996514) on the mongolite github site

Comment: This fully resolved my issue. Thank you for this answer and thank you for the work you are doing with `mongolite` and `mongolitedt`.

Comment: You're welcome. And Jeroen Ooms has done all the work, I'm merely "standing on his shoulders". Make sure to check the `* 1000` is doing what you expect (as per my question I've linked to), too.