# Convert POSIXct object to Epoch time in milliseconds as a string, avoiding integer overflow?

Tags: r, datetime, posixct

We're using an API which wants the Epoch time in milliseconds as one of it's parameters.

Originally I was using

```
milli <- paste0(as.integer(posix) * 1000)
```

but obviously due to R's 32-bit integers that broke fairly quickly because it was implicitly converted to a double when the date got too high. Then I tried

```
milli <- paste0(as.integer(posix), "000")
```

but again that has a finite lifespan.

[Another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36562894/r-converting-posixct-to-miliseconds) suggested using `options(scipen = 1000)`, which works but means that you don't get scientific printing. If that really is the only way to do this then it'll do, but is there a way to go from POSIXct to epoch time in milliseconds as a string without having to convert to numeric first?

I'm happy to use any packages if that's needed.

Comment: Could this be something that can work? http://www.inside-r.org/questions/how-convert-posixct-numeric-milliseconds

Comment: What is your (ultimate) date range? One option may be to first remove a given number of seconds (for instance depending on year) from your source posix, so that numeric outcome results to the value without first digits (in character) then paste those digits. Not simple I do agree...

Comment: @Arun that also loses scientific printing. It's the solution we're using at the moment, but it does make reading big numbers a pain.

Comment: @EricLecoutre It will be running indefinitely, but data only started being taken in 2013 so that might be an option. I'll look into it and post back if it works, thanks.

Comment: Don't fear 22th century bug ;) Note that it also looses scientific printing.

Comment: Would knowing the date, hour, min,sec be a necessity for the computation? cause you could separate the date, hour, min, sec from the millisec and have a millisec variable..

Answer (score 0):

converting like `'as.numeric(as.POSIXct(object$datum,tz='UTC')) * 1000’` should give you no problems regarding overflow. Change time zone ‘tz’ to your liking.

Answer (score 0):

The best method I've found so far is to temporarily change the print format, like so:

```
old_options <- options(scipen = 1000)
milli <- paste0(as.numeric(posix) * 1000)
options(old_options)
```

It feels brittle, but it works for now.