# Is this a bug in mongolite package?

Tags: r, mongodb, mongolite

Hi I'm tyring to update collection in mongodb using `mongolite` package, but I can't figure out why is my query failing(google was of no help).

I'm tring to run update command but I I get error saying that timestamp is invalid:

```
files$update(
  query  = "{\"FileId\" : \"F0FFFBDA14E1D49547C24CD5150\" }",
  update = "{ \"$set\" : {\"Contract\" : \"1\"},  
              \"$currentDate\" : {\"Updated\" : { \"$type\" : \"timestamp\" } }  }")
```

> Error: Invalid input string timestamp, looking for 6

This is the object that I'm trying to udpate:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("59d3fc93ec2d602b7967f4a7"), 
    "Client" : "Someone", 
    "FileId" : "F0FFFBDA14E1D49547C24CD5150"
}
```

I pretty sure that my query is correct I was able to execute it in `mongo` shell client.

Comment: and `"$type" : "date" ` fails too

Comment: The error appears to be generated from within the `c` BSON library, [right here](https://github.com/jeroen/mongolite/blob/d907acae27042e61aef525cf88db58f8418b31c9/src/bson/bson-json.c#L669)

Comment: @SymbolixAU thanks for quick response, I'm not a C programmer so I couldn't tell much of what's going on in `mongolite` code base but it looks like 6 in error message refers to BSON_JSON_IN_BSON_TYPE_DATE_ENDMAP a member of enum  bson_json_read_state_t.

Comment: After I left work I thought of a work around(to be tested tomorrow), supply the timestamp myself. It seems that `mongolite` had a lot of issues with dates in the past and they patched a lot of bugs so there should be a way to enter `Sys.time()` into the query.

Comment: yeah I've encountered issues with datetimes in mongolite too, for example [in this question & answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36563386/5977215), and [here's another useful reference](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34454034/5977215)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using mongolite's documetnation I found out how to add my own timestamp, which happens to be time now.

Basically instead of using `$currentDate` operator I used `$set` and with a littlebit of R code I figured out what value shoudl I set `Updated` field to:

```
sub(
  "NOW",
  format(Sys.time(), "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ", 'EST'),
  '"$set" : {"Updated" : "NOW"}'
)
```

See [documentation](https://jeroen.github.io/mongolite/query-data.html#select-by-date) for more details.